# spacing images horizontally on titlepage

Tags: spacing, graphics, titles

Good day, i  have inserted and aligned three logo images at the top of the title page, but they are not separated; i don't know how to spacing them horizontally. Next the code that i have made:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}%

\end{titlepage} 

\end{document}`
```

The result:

[image]

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\hfill` command to space out the figures regularly in the horizontal direction.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \hfill
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        \hfill
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
    \end{titlepage} 
\end{document}
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

If you would like to specify the horizontal spacing yourself (say, 1cm), try `\hspace{1cm}` instead of `\hfill`.